# Deployment an ASP.NET webform application to a windows hosting security error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment

I tried to deploy my application (ASP.NET) to a windows hosting server, and I get the following message:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Security Exception Description: The
>   application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
>   security policy.  To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the application's
>   trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request failed.]
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly
>   asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +96
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object
>   assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +80
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet
>   grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString,
>   SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +288
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack
>   cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet
>   demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm,
>   SecurityAction action) +70
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName) +70    System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid()
>   +12    System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection
>   ps) +2045
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash()
>   +107    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64
>   cachedHash) +458
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64
>   cachedHash) +51
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2558.0

How I can resolve this issue ??

Comment: The host provider might have enforced partial trust https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/tkscy493(v=vs.100).aspx, which is in fact not secure at all, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2698981/asp-net-partial-trust-does-not-guarantee-application-isolation Talk to them to give you a full trust environment, or modify your code to work in partial trust way.

Comment: This is permission issue. Please just kindly ask your registrar to give full permission for you and I guarantee it will fix your problem. :)